# Linux Mint 13 XFCE freezes when external monitor connected

Tags: linux, multi-monitor, laptop

I am running Linux Mint 13. The problem is that whenever I connect/disconnect an external monitor to my laptop it freezes. If the monitor is connected on boot it works fine. Any ideas ?

Output from inxi -SGxc 0

```
System:    Host: ****-VGN-NS140E Kernel: 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.6.3) 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.10.0 (Gtk 2.24.10) Distro: Linux Mint 13 Maya
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.11.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: vesa,fbdev) Resolution: 1280x800@59.9hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Comment: Is the monitor connected to a VGA port?

Comment: Yes it is on VGA

Comment: I had a similar problem - there is some XFCE functionality trying to configure that automagically, which can fail (badly). My workaround has been a simple script that I've used to call `xrandr` to set up/disable the external output, which has somehow sorted it out (not sure how, but I don't experience the freezes any more).

Comment: Can u share that script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script as mentioned in comment to the question:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr \
    --output LVDS-1 \
    --auto \
    --dpi 145 \
    --left-of DVI-D-1 \
    --output DVI-D-1 \
    --primary \
    --auto \
    --dpi 96
sleep 1
killall -USR1 xfce4-panel
```

This makes the DVI-connected device the main display device and positions the laptop screen (LVDS) to the left of DVI. Names of the devices vary - check output of `xrandr -q` for names on your system. After the configuration settles down, xfce4-panel is signalled to reload itself - this is mostly to ensure, that the workspace switcher updates its cached desktop sizes (without this it would only display a single screen miniatures).

To disable the monitor you need something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output DVI-D-1 --off
sleep 1
killall -USR1 xfce4-panel
```

You might also want to check *Session and Startup* entry in the XCE Settings manager fo anything that would resemble an application that would try to do this automagically and possibly remove it (I can't remember whether this was a standalone service or whether it was part of the widow manager).